# How to detach the ALSA driver?

Tags: python, linux, audio, usb, alsa

I am working on an application which needs to use more than 32 USB sound cards. It is written in python and I'm testing it on Ubuntu 12.04. Some useful modules I'm using are pyusb and pyalsaaudio.

My problem is that the ALSA driver can handle 32 sound devices at most, so, since the application will not need to simultaneously output to all of them (and it couldn't either, because of the bandwidth limitation), I was thinking of detaching the ALSA driver from the USB cards, and attaching it when needed (using some sort of queue).

I can currently recognize all of the USB devices (after installing the 3.6 kernel, which allows the system to handle them) and get a representation of them with pyusb. I tried (for a test with 3 cards):

```
>>> import usb.core
>>> import usb.util
>>> cards = []
>>> cards.append(usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0d8c))
>>> cards.append(usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0c76))
>>> cards.append(usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1130))
>>> len(cards)
3
>>> for c in cards:
...     c.detach_kernel_driver(0)
...
```

which successfully removes the cards from the output of `aplay -L`. However, they still show up in the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`, so I'm afraid the ALSA driver is not being detached (if you could explain why they disappear from one but not the other, it would be helpful too).

Are there any commands I can run (maybe from the terminal, not necessarily from python) to detach/re-attach the ALSA driver from a specific sound card?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What on earth are you doing that needs 32 USB audio interfaces? Surely if it's channel count you're after, fewer higher-channel count interfaces are the way to go?  You'd get a lot more bang for the buck with S800 IEEE1394.  There's also at least one Thunderbolt-based interface on the market with a crazy channel count - I think from RME.

Any limit imposed by ALSA is artificial and likely a compile-time constant somewhere in the drivers.  Your challenge is finding it ;)

Comment: What is the output of `lsof /dev/snd/*`?